# Linq keyword to Create all possible KeyValue Pairs from a set of Keys and a set of Values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
Array KeyArr = {"Key1","Key2","Key3"}
Array ValArr = {"Value1","Value2","Value3"}
```

Here is the list of Key Value Pairs I am expecting

```
{Key1,Value1}
{Key2,Value1} , {Key2,Value2}
{Key3,Value1} , {Key3,Value2} , {Key3,Value3}
```

I can achieve it with a for loop statement but
I am just wondering if there is already a built in functionality to achieve it 
where I supply the Arrays and offset for Each key...(For demo purpose I made the offset coincident with the Key position...)

If not... can anyone suggest a better and clever algorithm than the one below

```
int Key1Offset = 1;int Key2Offset = 2;int Key3Offset = 3;

var lst = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();

for(int i=0;i<KeyArr.Count;i++)
{
 if(i < Key1Offset) lst.Add(new KeyvaluePair<int,int>(KeyArr(1),ValArr(i)));
 if(i < Key2Offset) lst.Add(new KeyvaluePair<int,int>(KeyArr(2),ValArr(i)));
 if(i < Key3Offset) lst.Add(new KeyvaluePair<int,int>(KeyArr(3),ValArr(i)));
}
```

*Please try to suggest a Built In function before suggesting a custom code...*

*Atleast a built In function that creates pairs from 2 different sets would suffice..(forget about the offset)*

Comment: Your sample doesn't look like all possible key/value pairs, or you'd also have Key1,Value2, for example. If you're wanting that type of result, there's not going to be anything built in.

Comment: @Jacob Sorry for the wrong title..The question I have asked is a subset of the title..so I felt it is justified...

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want *all* key/value pairs:

```
var pairs = 
    from key in KeyArr
    from value in ValArr
    select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value);
```

If you wanted your sample output:

```
var pairs =
    from idx in Enumerable.Range(KeyArr.Count())
    from value in ValArr.Take(idx + 1)
    select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(KeyArr[idx], value);
```